# How to use quotas with Javascript in Qualtrics

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I am developing a survey in which I ask 24 demographic questions and put the users into one of 7 categories based on them, using clustering with group centers for the 7 categories. I want to add quotas based on the categories the users are in.

Not using Javascript would lead to an *extremely large* number of rules. However I am not able to figure out how to implement Quotas using Javascript -- how can I implement them using JS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JavaScript to set embedded data field values, then base your quota logic on the embedded data fields.